# UIButton selector not called inside Navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a `UIButton` to the center of my navigation bar.

My navigation controller is initialised with a tab bar controller.
Then I create a `UIButton` with a custom image.

My problem is that the selector is never called, even if I can see that the button is really pressed, as the image animation (when pushing the button) is played.

Here is my code:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)

let image = UIImage(named: "logo")

let but = UIButton(type: .Custom)
navigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(but)
but .setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
but.frame=CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-image!.size.width)/2.0, (navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-image!.size.height)/2.0, image!.size.width, image!.size.height)

but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.initTabView), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.initTabView), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Where you have defined the selector method?

Comment: in the same class where I put these lines of code

Comment: try adding target as `but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(initTabView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)` and make sure initTabView method is not taking any parameter

Comment: still the same issue.

Comment: BUT I tried to put the code of initTabView in different classes.
And the code of initTabView in my AppDelegate is called!!!
BUT the app crashes...

Comment: if I put the code in custom class MyTabBarController, it's called but after 2 presses it crashes again. Really strange

Comment: looks like the crash is due to something else, a message sent to deallocated instance (my tab controller is released meanwhile). I've to dound that one now. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at `forControlEvents`:

```
let but =  UIButton(type: .Custom)
but.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40) 
but.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
but.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyTabBarController.initTabView), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.titleView = but
```

To prevent multiple touch on your button:

```
// default is false
but.exclusiveTouch = true
```

Comment: Have you removed this line:navigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(but) ?

Comment: yes I did. maybe it's because of my tab bar controller... but I can't understand the problem :(

Comment: I put this code in wiewdidload and now the button is displayed. BUT the app crashes after pressing the button twice, and the function initTabView can be the root cause as I just print something there. thanks for the help!

Comment: This is simple , but.exclusiveTouch = true (the default is false)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114044/discussion-between-alessandro-ornano-and-alx).

Comment: looks like the crash is due to something else, a message sent to deallocated instance (my tab controller is released meanwhile). I've to dound that one now. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

// try like this
// Classname is , in which class initTabView method exist you need to give that class name

```
 but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Classname.initTabView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I tried that : but.addTarget(myTabBarController, action: #selector(MyTabBarController.initTabView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) and the initTabView function wall called successfully but after 2 calls, the app crashes, and before that the initTabView function was called in the AppDelegate !!!

Comment: declare myTabBarController globally

Comment: same crash unfortunately!

Comment: do one thing declare that method in appdelagate and give classname as Appadelagate

Comment: looks like the crash is due to something else, a message sent to deallocated instance (my tab controller is released meanwhile). I've to dound that one now. thanks for your help!